# closest to average value SQL

Tags: sql

I am looking for a query to get the closest value exists to the average of all values.
for example,
I have in column A the values - 1 , 2, 8
The average is 3.667 . So i want the query to return 2 since it is the closest to the average value.

Comment: Actually in my DB i have 2 columns- Width and Height . I am calculating the square size , than calculating the average square size. and i want to get the Width and Height, which their square size is the most close to this average.
How can i do it?

Comment: Why so many upvotes? This question shows absolutely no effort.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT TOP 1 myTable.*
FROM myTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(A) AS averageA FROM myTable) AS averageA
ORDER BY ABS(averageA.averageA - myTable.A)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce4aa/5)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT number, ABS(number - (SELECT AVG(number) FROM numberTable)) AS deviation 
FROM numberTable 
ORDER BY deviation ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(A)
FROM myTable
WHERE A < (SELECT AVG(A) AS averageA FROM myTable)
```

Comment: -1: Consider the case with numbers (1, 5, 8). Average = 4.67 and the closest number is 5, not 1.

Comment: @SparKot: If OP would've shown this example, I could have come up with a diff. answer.